# Проблемы с капчей

Tags: поддержка

Иногда возникает предложение пройти антиботовую защиту, и она у меня не работает корректно: нет окна, куда надо поставить галочку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Браузер Vivaldi, блокировщики рекламы на этом сайте отключены.

Более того, я хотел обратиться с этой проблемой в поддержку, а не сюда, но не могу: по-видимому, там тоже должна быть капча, но у меня просто пустота:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]